# terraform with json files

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I've a requirement just to list the given scope using json file. I tried a few options but it didn't work

**user_info.json** file

```
{
    "user1" : [{
        "value" : 1001,
        "scope" : "development",
        "service_name" : "application1"
        }],
    "user2" : [{
        "value" : 1002,
        "scope" : "development",
        "service_name" : "application1"
    }],
    "user3" : [{
        "value" : 1003,
        "scope" : "Kubernetes",
        "service_name" : "application1"
    }],
    "user4" : [{
        "value" : 1004,
        "scope" : "Kubernetes",
        "service_name" : "application1"
    }],
    "user5" : [{
        "value" : 1005,
        "scope" : "development",
        "service_name" : "application2"
    }],
    "user6" : [{
        "value" : 1006,
        "scope" : "development",
        "service_name" : "application2"
    }]
}
```

requirement is just to list the scope which is development

```
user_info  = jsondecode(file("${path.module}/user_info.json"))
user_name = keys(local.user_info)
user_with_development_scope = [ for k in local.user_info : k if v.scope == "development" ] (This is where I've the challenge. I just need to list users only but it doesn't print the users)
```

Is possible to list the users with scope development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just use the [for expression](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/for) over the full data structure.

*note: This does assume there is only one item in the information array.*

```
locals {
  user_info = jsondecode(file("${path.module}/user_info.json"))
}

output "development_users" {
  value = [
    for k, v in local.user_info :
    k if v[0].scope == "development"
  ]
}
```

Which gives output:

```
Changes to Outputs:
  + development_users = [
      + "user1",
      + "user2",
      + "user5",
      + "user6",
    ]
```